# how to force the text to be placed at the provided orientation parameter

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

why when i change the orientation parameter of a JLabel object it does not obey it.
in the following lines of code:

```
    headerLabel = new JLabel("headerLabel", JLabel.LEFT);
    statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.RIGHT);
    jPanel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    jPanel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

whatever the orientation parameters order (EAST;WEST;LEFT;RIGHT), the result is always that, "headerLabel" to the left and "statusLabel" to the right.

how to force the text to be placed at the provided orientation parameter.

**code**:

```
private void prepareGUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Swing Example");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    headerLabel = new JLabel("headerLabel", JLabel.LEFT);
    statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.RIGHT);
    jPanel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    jPanel.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jPanel.add(statusLabel);

    mainFrame.add(jPanel);

    //mainFrame.getContentPane().add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //mainFrame.getContentPane().add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(false);
    //mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
    //mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You are adding the "headerLabel" to the frame twice. Fix your code a post a proper `SSCCE`(http://sscce.org/) if you still need more help. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/execute to see the incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The default layout for JPanel using its no parameter constructor is FlowLayout. Set the layout of jPanel to BorderLayout if you wish to layout its components using that LayoutManager

```
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
//use the BorderLayout parameters to add components to jPanel
```